# Existence of superior limit of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I have a little doubt. These quantities

$\inf_{n}  f_n $ , $\sup_n f_n$

are function only if the there exist the infimum of {$f_n(x)$} $\forall x $ and is different from $\infty$.

And the same is for the superior and inferior limit.

Am I right?

For instance, for the sequence of constant function $f_n(x) = n$ we can't define $\sup_n f_n $ right?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean by $\inf_n$, what is $n$ supposed to mean?

Comment: In your example, if $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$, then we would have $\inf_n f_n(x) = 1$.

Comment: I meant $sup_n f_n$

Comment: We can , it's just the function $f(x) = +\infty$. In measure theory we usually work in the extended reals $[-\infty, +\infty]$.

Comment: Henno Brandsma, thanks! So we treat $\infty$ as a real number? Do you have any pdf explaining this?